# Context and Activity's reference

Tags: android, android-activity, assets, android-context

I've some problem with the design of my app, especially opening assets from a class, different from the main Activity.

This part of my project is a webserver and there are 2 classes: WebServer and WebPage. WebServer has these methods:
`start(), get(), post(), send(WebPage)` and some constructors;

WebPage has 2 variables: `String head` (the HTTP header) and `byte [] body` (the content who can be text or any file).
WebPage has one method, `byte[] getFile(String filename)`, used by constructors to save the bytes of the file in body. The file is an asset.

When the Activity starts (`onCreate()`), it creates an instance of WebServer, call start() and stay in listening. When the server receives a GET request, it parses it and it creates a WebPage object using the filename to open the asset. Finally WebServer just sends the page with send(WebPage).

Which is the best way to obtain an Activity's reference from the WebPage class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question should be more explained: you want to keep your WebServer as generic as possible so that it works on Android and on a PC.

Do the following. Create your generic WebServer:

```
public class WebServer{
    int port;
    public WebServer(int port){
        this.port = port;
    }
    ////////bla bla bla
}
```

Create your android WebServer

```
public class AndroidWebServer extends WebServer{
    Context mContext;
    public webserver(Context mContext, int port){
        super(port);
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
}
```

---

**Old Answer**

Use the very usual way and don't worry about memory leak.

```
public class webserver{
    Context mContext;
    public webserver(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
}
```

In your activity:

```
webserver A = new webserver(this);
```

Comment: Ok! So, there is no way to do the opposite operation (eg. an instruction to get activity's reference directly from inside WebPage class)!? is `getApplicationContext()` suitable for this purpose?

Comment: That's not the opposite! Can you please explain why dont you want to pass it in the constructor?

Comment: I would have a smaller and more versatile constructor for WebServer and WebPage, something like: `WebServer(int port)` and `WebPage(String filename)`. Also I would have (as more as possible) a "general purpose" WebServer class, to be used both for android and PC. But if it's the best solution I think I'll create several constructor, with and without the Context parameter.

Comment: It is okay ! Leave your WebServer Generic class and create `DroidWebServer extends WebServer` and add the relevant constructor to it?

Comment: @supergiox For people to help you you should tick their answers :) There is a tick beside the answer! When someone answers you correctly tick it for them .. Believe me

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new member and I haven't seen it. Also I would vote up your answer, but I've not enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a parameter in the constructor, or add a method so your activity will be able to pass itself.